# React Hook UseEffect with className

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is it not possible to update classNames on rerender?

```
const [selected, setSelectedState] = useState(true);

let className = "none";
useEffect(() => {
    className = "appointment-item " + (selected ? "selected" : "");
    console.log(className );
}, [selected] );


return (
  <div className={`${className}`} onClick={()=>setSelectedState(!selected)}>{Math.random()}</div>
);
```

`className` in the console shows correctly, but when the div rerenders (which i see because the random number updates), the className stays as "none". I am also confused because I thought useEffect runs immediately as well.. so it should never be "none" in the first place becuase it should get overwritten right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need `useEffect` since `selected` already defined as a state, and you can compute the class name from `selected`

```
const [selected, setSelectedState] = useState(true);

const className = "appointment-item " + (selected ? "selected" : "");

return (
  <div className={className} />
)
```

Answer (score 6):

To add more details on @MarkoCen answers (that is right), there are few things to know when working with hooks:

- `useEffect` runs **after** each render.
- On each render, the component re-executes from beginning, after the hooks definition. Given your code (I added comments to identity each cycle)

```
const [selected, setSelectedState] = useState(true); // 0

let className = "none"; // 1

useEffect(() => { 
    // 3
    className = "appointment-item " + (selected ? "selected" : "");
    console.log(className );
}, [selected] );

// 2
return (
  <div className={`${className}`} onClick={()=>setSelectedState(!selected)}>{Math.random()}</div>
);
```

Here are the cycles in order:

First render:

- 0: useState
- 1: className = none
- 2: render with className = none
- 3: useEffect

Re-renders:

- 1: className = none
- 2: re-render with className = none
- 3: useEffect

As you can see, each render set `className` to "none" each time, so you will never have what you expect.

Comment: Thank you! this was very very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using a `useState` hook for the `className` variable if you want to use `useEffect`:

```js
const [selected, setSelectedState] = useState(true);
const [className , setClassName] = useState("none");

useEffect(() => {
    setClassName("appointment-item " + (selected ? "selected" : ""))
    console.log(className );
}, [selected] );


return (
  <div className={className} onClick={()=>setSelectedState(!selected)}>{Math.random()}</div>
);
```

But I highly recommend @MarkoCen response.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have an useEffect for this.

all you need,

```
const [selected, setSelectedState] = useState(true);

let clsName = 'appointment-item ' + (selected ? 'selected' : '');

return(
<div className={`${clsName}`} onClick={() => setSelectedState(!selected)}>
{Math.random()}
</div>
)
```